# How to make a field required in Microsoft Access form based on the criteria of another

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, ms-office, required

**Form Name: Inventory_Adjustments**

**Field One: Qty_Adjusted**

**Field Two: Approved_By**

Hello, I am trying to achieve the following and cannot figure out how.

-User inputs Qty_Adjusted Value less than 3, Approved_By is not required.

-User inputs Qty_Adjusted equal to 3, Approved_By is required with message "seek 
 level 1 approval".

-User inputs Qty_Adjusted between 3 and 10, Approved_By is required with message 
 "seek level 2 approval".

-User inputs Qty_Adjusted greater than 10, Approved_By is required with message 
 "seek level 3 approval".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you are going to put a check on the `Qty_Adjusted` field in the Before_Update event.

Then you are probably going to have either a nested if, or an if-then-else chain for each condition. Pseuedo code:

```
If less than three, do nothing
else if equal to 3 then check the value of `Approved_By` is at least 1
else if less than 10 then check the value of `Approved_By` is at least 2
else then check the value of `Approved_By` is at least 3
```

Display errors/messages in each section as appropriate and then abort the update.
Otherwise, let the update proceed as normal.